# AngularJs http get response is undefined But the data is present inside success function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am new to angular. I have tried to get the json response from http get method.

My code is,

```
app.factory('getdata', function ($http, $q){
  this.getlist = function(){       
    alert('1');
    return $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php',{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost:*'})
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('response'); console.log(response.data); //I get the correct items, all seems ok here
        alert('2');
        return response.data;
      });            
  }
  return this;
});
/* Stream page controller */
app.controller('streamCtrl', function($scope,getdata, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $timeout, $ionicScrollDelegate, $location, $sce){
  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
  getdata.getlist()
  .then(function(arrItems){
   $scope.sliders = arrItems;         
 });
alert($scope.sliders);
```

am getting the alert like 1, 'undefined' and 2
but the $scope.sliders has the data. because It was working once I resize the screen and also I can get correct alert inside the

```
getdata.getlist().then(function(arrItems) {
  $scope.sliders = arrItems;         
  alert($scope.sliders);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason for getting alert is `undefined` is **because you haven't define `$scope.sliders`** in controller and `http` request is async so `alert($scope.sliders);` function call before getting `data` from response and setting that data to `$scope.sliders`.

You get `alert($scope.sliders);` value only after getting success response.

Other possibility is you can set `$scope.sliders = {}` and then use `alert($scope.sliders);` which show `{}` in alert when `then` function is called `alert` shows actual response.

Original [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/moOfwxFNM5ttH9wBzzvk?p=preview) based on issue

Check comments and updated code in new [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UsKZbhVVeGiRipU9BVSr?p=preview)

Comment: Still am getting the alert($scope.sliders) as undefined

Comment: @SarjanDesai Try not to update answer from others, atleast put some courtesy

Comment: @Alex Man I'm trying complete my answer which was incomplete earlier

Comment: Could you please try this now http://plnkr.co/edit/moOfwxFNM5ttH9wBzzvk?p=preview

Comment: Check updated answer with new added plnkr and read comments in plnkr

Comment: So Its ok, But While rendering in my page I was working only on resizing the page

Comment: It has nothing to do with resizing and I'm not getting what you are trying to do with resize and this request response....

Comment: Actually while rendering this json data to the templates it shows empty data , but while resizing window width .the will be shown good

Comment: Don't resize window, when response get, it will automatically show data on view...

Comment: I waited for a long time I didn't get response. Once I resize I will get immediate response

Comment: Are you talking about plunkr example?

Answer (score 4):

`$http` is a asynchronous call, so what happens is that you have triggered a http call at **line number 6** while it gets the response the **line number 10** will be executed since all `http` calls in angular are asynchronous.

[image]

That is why you are getting `undefined`

If you want to do anything after the response just do the stuff within the http promise ie. within the `.then` function block like as shown below

```
getdata.getlist()
  .then(function(response){ // http promise block
     $scope.sliders = response.data;
     console.log($scope.sliders);
});
```

Comment: Could you please try here http://plnkr.co/edit/moOfwxFNM5ttH9wBzzvk?p=preview am still getting undefined

Comment: @AnandhakumarR I have seen your plunker, just like `.then`,  `.success` is another http promise, you have placed the alert outside the promise, that is why you are getting undefined

Comment: @AnandhakumarR `alert($scope.names)` will get executed before the http call get finished, that's why it is recommended to put everything within the promise block ie. `.success` or `.then` function block